# Why were the drug stampers dressed this way?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, luke-cage-2016

At the very beginning of Season 2, Luke breaks up an operation that was putting his name on drugs, advertising them as "bulletproof".

All the people putting the stamps on the drugs seem to be female, and dressed in their underwear. Why is this? Clearly it's not because it's extremely hot, because the guards are dressed. Is it meant to keep them uneasy, so they can be exploited better? So the guards can ogle them? Or what?

Comment: So they don't have anywhere to hide drugs they might steal.....it's a common thing *apparently*.

Comment: @Paulie_D: if you have a source stating it is common, that would be a great answer.

Comment: It something I've seen in many movies/shows so it's a trope, presumably based on real life.

Comment: For the same reason many casino dealers don't have pockets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a fairly common media trope (Fast Five, GTAV, Sons of Anarchy, Hitman: Blood Money, New Jack City), etc and one that [mirrors](https://thecrimereport.org/2006/12/21/dea-details-bust-of-pa-heroin-mill-that-used-fentanyl/#) [reality](https://tinyurl.com/ya7p6kxf), albeit with more attractive drug makers.

There are three main reasons;

- Cocaine and heroin are very expensive. No pockets = less theft
- Ether is a common substance used in drug manufactury. Given its flammability your choices are to either provide costly fireproof clothes or make your staff work in their (easily extinguished) skin
- Most illegals drugs have a distinctive smell. If your workers aren't wearing their clothes, they can make it past sniffer dogs more easily.

From a movie perspective, it's also a way of getting scantily clad women (who are invariably aged between 18-30, slim and attractive) past the censors.

Comment: So, does this really happen, then? Can you cite an article or something?

Comment: @Adamant - "*Workers in heroin mills typically are forced to work in the nude to prevent theft.*" - https://thecrimereport.org/2006/12/21/dea-details-bust-of-pa-heroin-mill-that-used-fentanyl/#

Comment: @Adamant - "*Barnes set out to organize an African American Mafia on the Italian model by organizing other prominent black drug dealers into a seven-member council and dividing up the drug traffickers' territories around New York City. He established so-called heroin mills in which women, working naked to protect against theft, cut and bagged the heroin powder.*" - [The War on Drugs: An International Encyclopedia](https://tinyurl.com/ya7p6kxf), etc etc etc

Comment: So, the *underwear* might actually be the unrealistic part?

Comment: @Adamant - Most of them seem to be riffing off of New Jack City where the drug girls were topless.